# Vue.js 2: Watch but not on initial data fetch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm new in the Vueniverse (using Vue.js 2) and I'm struggling with `watch`. On `mounted`, I call an API and set the radio button to the value I got from the API, so basically I have two radio buttons with values `1` and `0` (true/false).

I think the watcher works correctly, because it does trigger when the value is changed. However, I don't want it to trigger on the *initial* change - that's when I first set the value from the backend.

I've tried with different lifecycle hooks, such as `beforeCreated`, `created` and so on and it always triggers.

Probably it's something easy to do but I can't figure out how and don't find information on the Internet (might using the wrong keywords).

The code:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: 'Settings',

  data: () => ({
    /* set motionSensor to null initially */
    motionSensor: null
  }),
  mounted() {
    /* get the initial value from the backend, however this triggers the watcher */
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:8000/status.json')
      .then(response => {
        response.data['motionsensor'] ? this.motionSensor = "1" : this.motionSensor = "0";
      })
  },
  watch: {
    motionSensor: function(val) {
      alert('Motion sensor value is now: ' + val)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to take advantage from the old value which is 2nd parameter of the watch handler :

```js
watch: {
  motionSensor: function(val, oldVal) {
    if (oldVal !== null) {
      alert('Motion sensor value is now: ' + val)
    }
  }
}
```